# Will apple delete photos if i stop paying for iCloud?

Tags: icloud, photos

Will apple delete 50 GB of photos from icloud if i stop paying for iCloud? Or is it just not possible to add new photos to iCloud? Will other data will be synchronized as notes?

Comment: I don’t think they delete the photos, at least not right away, but all syncing, backups, and sharing stops until you clean things out.  I do know that you will have full access until the end of the billing cycle, so it’s not instant.

Comment: I had a card issue and nothing stopped or was lost - but it was only a few days. However are you expecting to have them store your photos for free for decades?

Comment: @SolarMike yes, I want to store for years

Comment: Then you have to pay for years, or buy your own personal storage and sort that.

Comment: @SolarMike if apple doesn't remove it, then why pay?

Comment: @Alex78191 so stop paying and see how long you get. Let us know

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [Downgrade or cancel your iCloud+ plan](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT207594#whathappens):

> #### What happens when you downgrade or cancel iCloud+
>
> - If your iCloud storage exceeds your new storage plan capacity, iCloud won't sync or update your information. iCloud updates again when you increase your storage capacity or delete information to make more space.
> - If you downgrade to the free iCloud plan, you will no longer have access to [iCloud+ features](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201238) like Hide My Email, Private Relay, and HomeKit Secure Video support.<sup>2</sup>
>
> […]
>
> <sup>2. Not all features are available in all countries or regions.</sup>

So there is no suggestion that your photos or other data will be deleted.  But you will lose **all** synchronisation. Put another way, your iCloud becomes read-only.